# Calculate the number of elements of this set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following sets:

$A = \{x \in N \mid x$ is a prime number and $x \lt 15\}$

$B = \{x\cdot y \mid x \in A$ and $y \in A$ and $x \ne y\}.$

How many elements does the set $B$ have?

a) 15,$\;\;$ b) 20, $\;\;$c) 25,$\;\;$ d) 30, $\;\;$e) 35?

The exercise solution gives "a)" as the correct answer ($B$ has $20$ elements), but I got "$21$ numbers" as the answer for the question "how many elements does set B have?".

For me $A = \{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13\}$ and $B$ = {1x2, 1x3, 1x5, 1x7, 1x11, 1x13, 2x3, 2x5, 2x7, 2x11, 2x13, 3x5, 3x7, 3x11, 3x13, 5x7, 5x11, 5x13, 7x11, 7x13, 11x13} = {1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 6, 10, 14, 22, 26, 15, 21, 33, 39, 35, 55, 65, 77, 91, 143} and therefore set $B$ has 21 elements?

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$ is not a prime, so $A$ has six members, making $15$ the correct answer.  If $n$ is the number of elments of $A$, there are $\frac 12n(n-1)$ in $B$-you don't have to list them.

Comment: Thanks, i missed the definition of prime numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the formula also!

Answer (score 3):

The number "$1$" is not prime. So your set $A$ has $|A| = 6$ elements.

There are $6$ prime elements $x \in A$ that can be multiplied by $5$ elements $y \in A, y\neq x$, giving $30$ products to consider in $B$, but we need to halve $30$ because $30$ counts both  $x.y$ and $y.x$ as separate products:

This gives us $|B| = \dfrac{6\cdot 5}{2} = 15$.

So $(a) \;15\;$ is the correct answer.

(If $1$ were a prime, then there would be $(7\cdot6)/2 = 21$ elements in B. But by definition, $1$ is excluded in the definition of a prime number.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.